# I don't see IE compatibility mode in Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility, mode

I have a problem wit IE compatibility mode in Edge.
Edge version : Version 101.0.1210.39 (Official build) (64-bit)
OS: Win 10 LTSB and Windows Server 2016
On first screenshot You can see domain policies which are applied on machines
[Domain policies screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaLab.png)

Inside Micosoft edge in  Settings-> Default browser i can only set Edge as default browser because i don't see any other option
[Edge default browser menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9t8M.png)

Additionally in Edge menu i don't see "Reload in Internet Explorer mode" button [Menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAaE6.png)

I'm looking for solution how to enable that compatibility mode. Any ideas?
[IE diagnosticData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K52fz.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be a result of something else instead of policies, particularly OS. You can check out the [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-local-site-list#prerequisites) of local site list for IE mode.

Obviously, Windows Server 2016 doesn't support this feature:

> This local site list feature isn't supported on Windows Server 2016 at this time.

For Windows 10, please check the detailed version and the updates needed.

---

Having looked into your IE mode diagnostic information, we can come to the following conclusion:

1. EMIE site list is unable to be parsed, which refers to a site list error.
2. The location of your site list directly leads to Google, where a domain name is not allowed. To correctly set a location, please use a **.xml** file.
   For more information of enterprise mode site list, please check out [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-using-the-configure-the-enterprise-mode-site-list-policy) and [this site list example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/enterprise-mode-schema-version-2-guidance#enterprise-mode-v2-schema-example).

Comment: That are prerequisites to local site list. IE mode should work on windows server 2016. That information is also on that same webpage

Comment: From your screenshot, if you are looking for "Reload in Internet Explorer mode" option, your OS does not meet the prerequisites. "Reload in Internet Explorer mode" option is available only when IE mode local site list is configured. However, you can still use IE mode by configuring IE mode policies. It looks like your IE mode policies are correctly configured. If you navigate to the site that is included in Enterprise Mode Site List, it will automatically be opened in IE mode.

Comment: If the sites you configured in IE mode policy doesn't load in IE mode, you can post your Internet Explorer mode diagnostic information screenshot of the following link for a further diagnosis: edge://compat/iediagnostic

Comment: I understand You but as i checked on other machine. IE mode not require that webpage will be added in Enterprise Mode Site list.  It should be possible to choose from menu to open current webpage in IE mode. And about prerequisites. As i checked on microsoft webpage that feature should work on windows server 2016 but with required update which is already installed on that machine.  I think that the problem is not with site list. Edge is not trying to open any webpage in IE mode even if it is on the list

Comment: I suggest you provide your IE mode diagnostic information screenshot for a further diagnosis. You can navigate to *edge://compat/iediagnostic* in Edge browser and take the screenshot.

Comment: IE Diagnostic data: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K52fz.png

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: @Rafalw1585 Is there any update about the issue? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Comment: Site list solution is working but that is only one part of problem. I still don't see option to manually enable IE mode or configure it inside msedge settings

Comment: That option is belong to local site list experience. Unfortunately, according to the [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-local-site-list#prerequisites), your OS does not meet the prerequisites.

Comment: About which prerequisites You are talking? OS version or maybe some KB's?

Comment: According to your IE diagnostic data, your OS version is Windows 10 version 1607, which does not meet the prerequisites. You can choose to update your OS to:
1) Windows 10 version 1909 - KB5003974 and KB5003698 or later. 2) Windows 10 version 2004. 3) Windows 10 version 20H2 or Windows 10 version 21H - KB5005260 and KB5005101 or later. 4) Windows 11. Please just check the doc I provide, you'll find these information.

Comment: It seems to be available only in More Tools -> Reload in Internet Explorer mode. M$ is progressively depreciating this option.